# Find derivative of $f(x)=(x+2)^{(x-1)}$

Tags: calculus

Find derivative of $f(x)=(x+2)^{(x-1)}$

What I did: 
$$f(x)=(x+2)^{(x-1)}= e^{{\ln(x+2)}^{(x-1)}}= e^{{(x-1)\ln(x+2)}}$$
$$f'(x)= e^{{(x-1)\ln(x+2)}}((x-1)\ln(x+2))'$$
$$f'(x)= e^{{\ln(x+2)}^{(x-1)}}(1\cdot \ln(x+2)+(x-1)\cdot (\frac {1}{x+2}))$$ ~so the solution is:
$$f'(x)= (x+2)^{(x-1)}( \ln(x+2)+\frac {x-1}{x+2})$$

Is this correct? (I got the right solution, but I've seen people solve this with $f′(x)=f(x)\frac {d}{dx}(\ln(f(x))$ (?!), and I've never used or seen this formula)

Comment: I just want to know if this is correct, so my next 25 calculations won't be solved wrong.

Comment: Never seen people do what exactly?  Everything looks good though.

Comment: Well, except for some "'"s that shouldn't be there anyway...

Comment: @Mike look at the best answer on the following link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72426/derivative-of-xx

Comment: Others might be taking the natural logarithm of both sides and then using implicit differentiation (chain rule, really). As in: $f'(x) / f(x) = D_x ((x-1)\ln(x+2))$.

Comment: Where shouldn't be $'''s$? Perhaps here: $f'(x)= (e^{{(x-1)ln(x+2)}}){\color{red}{'}}((x-1)ln(x+2)){\color{red}{'}}$?

Comment: In that line, the second should be there, but not the first.  You've already taken the derivative of that part.

Comment: Okay, I'll correct it! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct except for the second line,you must write $f'(x)=e^{(x-1)ln(x+2)}\cdot ((x-1)ln(x+2))'$ and not $f'(x)= (e^{{(x-1)ln(x+2)}})'((x-1)ln(x+2))'$

Answer (score 3):

Ok, but it is a bit simpler by taking logs first

$\quad \begin{eqnarray} \log(f) \,&=&\  (x-1)\ \log(x+2)\\ \\
\Rightarrow\ \ \ \ \dfrac{f'}f\, &=&\, \dfrac{x-1}{x+2} + \log(x+2)\end{eqnarray}$

Now multiply through by $\,f\,$ to obtain $\,f'.$

**Remark** $\ $ This handy method is known as *logarithmic differentiation.* Similarly

$$\rm (abc\: \cdots\: f)'\: =\ \: abc\:\cdots f\:\ \bigg(\frac{a'}{a} + \frac{b'}{b} + \frac{c'}{c} +\:\cdots\:+ \frac{f\:'}{f}\bigg) $$

Comment: What are $a$, $b$ and $c$ here?

Comment: @ziyuang Anything (differentiable) and $\ne 0$

Comment: Sounds like the same as $f$ except for the positiveness.

Comment: OK, I get it. It has nothing to do with the logarithm.

Comment: @ziyuang Positivity is not needed. The formula has a simple inductive proof using only the product rule for derivatives, e.g. see my [answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/90588/242) Using logs is simply a nice way to motivate the discovery of the formula, but not essential.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x > -2$.
Take the log on both sides:
$$ ln(f(x)) = (x-1)\,ln(x-2)$$
Differentiate, by the chain rule we get

$$ \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{x-1}{x+2} + ln(x + 2)$$

Thus we get,
$$ f'(x) = (x+2)^{(x-1)}(\frac{x-1}{x-2} + ln(x + 2))$$

Answer (score 1):

I checked your answer on Wolfram Alpha, and it is correct:

Their solution: 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%28x%2B2%29%5E%28x-1%29

They wrote the answer differently, but the following evaluates that it is the same as yours:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282+%2B+x%29%5E%28-2+%2B+x%29+%28-1+%2B+x+%2B+%282+%2B+x%29+Log%5B2+%2B+x%5D%29+%3D+%28x%2B2%29%5E%28x-1%29%28ln%28x%2B2%29+%2B+%28x-1%29%2F%28x%2B2%29+%29 .